# Deploy ASP.NET Core App Service with Azure DevOps path not found

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have a simple build pipeline that triggers on my git commit and is working great.

Here is the .yaml for that process:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
  - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
inputs:
  rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
  includeRootFolder: true
  archiveType: 'zip'
  archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
  replaceExistingArchive: true
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Then, I tried to make a Release build, but can't get the zip file across to my deploy step. The steps I follow are:

1. Publish build artifacts
2. Download build artifacts
3. Deploy web service

Here is my setup - Overall release pipeline:

[image]

Artifact Stage setup as follow:

[image]

Here is my 3 tasks in the Stage 1 (Deploy Stage):

[image]

Then the 3 tasks's properties:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And here is the error I'm getting, it is with regard to the artefact publish directory:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **dotnet publish** to create your binaries. The step will also create a zip file. Then to publish the artefacts, use the `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` Task. These steps should all be done *within a build*, not a release.

Here an example:

```
steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-o /app'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '/app'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Within the release, you don't need the Publish and Download Build Artefact step since the artefacts are already there (_ISOF). After you run the first Build, you can just select the zip file in the "Package or folder" dropdown.

Comment: I see, thanks! With regard to the publish location - what is this field related to, the path, the type of location? or what should I enter there? I'm stil new to azure dev ops so I'm still not sure if the storage space from build is accessible to release

Comment: "In most cases, Azure Pipelines/TFS (Server on TFS 2018 RTM and older) is the best and simplest option. Otherwise, choose a file share and then specify a few more arguments (see below). If left empty or container is specified, it will have the same effect as specifying Azure Pipelines/TFS. To learn more, see " See this Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops